# Unexpected token while using jquery on event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to bind on to a click event for a class but continue to get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

My jquery and HTML

```
function loadData() {

  isLoading = true;
  $('#loaderCircle').show();

  $.post(apiURL, { f: 'gridview', start: pgStart, end: pgEnd, params: $("#search_basic_form_id").serialize() }, function(data){
        if (data.success) {
            // Create HTML for the images.
            var html = '';

            $.each(data.profiles, function() {

                html += '<li><div class="image-wrapper">';
                html += '<div class="image-options">';
                html += '<a href="#" id="imgoption_'+this.user_id+'" class="favoriteButton" title="Add Favorite"><br>Favorite</a>';
                html += '</div>';
                html += '<a href="/view_profile.php?id='+this.user_id+'">';
                html += '<img src="'+this.file_name+'" width=200px; height="'+this.height+'px" style="border:0;">';
                html += '</a>';

                // Image title.
                html += '<p>'+this.name+' '+this.age+'</p>';
                html += '<p>'+this.city+', '+this.state+'</p>';
                html += '</div>';
                html += '</li>';                    
            });

            // Add image HTML to the page.
            $('#tiles').append(html);

            // Apply layout.
            applyLayout();

            pgStart = data.start;
            pgEnd = data.end;

        }
    }, "json");
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    // Load first data from the API.
    loadData();

    $('.favoriteButton').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        alert("Favorite Clicked");
    });
...
```

Not sure why I'm getting this error but it points to the last semi colon in the jquery call.

Comment: Wait why are there expressions in the middle of the HTML?  Is that HTML embedded in some other code of some sort?

Comment: Hmmm, nothing apparently wrong with what you posted.  Here is a Fiddle with that code: http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/jTutZ/  I was messing around with wiring up the event via .click, but both work fine in the Fiddle.  Can you post the rest of the js and markup from the page?

Comment: @Gromer I strongly doubt that the "id" of that `<a>` tag is really supposed to have "+this.user_id+" embedded in it.  I don't think the OP posted all the relevant code.

Comment: I don't see anything blantly wrong with what you posted.  Also it works in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/Jgwab/

Comment: @Pointy, it might be odd, but it isn't the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Gromer well I agree that the `new` was wrong, but if that HTML is actually supposed to be a multi-line string constant, that would be a problem too.

Comment: But you're also right.  The '+' isn't valid, per HTML spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id

Comment: @Pointy, ugh, I didn't see that right.  I see what he was trying to do with the ID now.  I misread some of that :o

Comment: That is not all the JavaScript you have. (Either that or you're using a *lot* of undefined variables.) It's most likely that there's missing  punctuation somewhere earlier in the file and it manifests only way later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, figured it out I think.  Try this for your document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Difference is the lack of new.

Comment: So what you posted here is all of the javascript you have on the page?  Try commenting out the contents of your document ready, so it is essentially empty, just to see if you still get the error.

Comment: Tried commenting everything else and I still get the error.  It only goes away when I comment out the favoriteButton click event...

Comment: So...if you ONLY have the doc ready, with ONLY the click wire up, it still breaks?  But some static html (html that you would normally get dynamically) on the page, and only wire up the click.

Comment: Must have been a typo somewhere. I copied a similar event and just renamed the class and the error goes away.  Weird.  Thanks for your help.  Any reason why I should remove new from document ready?

Comment: Honestly, I've never seen anyone do that, that's why I suggested it.  I thought it was causing an issue in the fiddle I made, but I was wrong.